# Temporal Acceleration and Linked Power

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Say you manifest Temporal Acceleration for 1 round, and while accelerated, manifest, using the Linked Power feat (Complete Psionics, page 62), power A linked with power B. Does power B kick in as soon as Temporal Acceleration ends, or does it somehow vanish in the seas of time?

The obvious use here is to pick Synchronicity as power B to effectively transform a swift action into a standard action. Other uses could be to obtain more move actions using Hustle and a duration of Temporal Acceleration longer than 1 round.

Comment: You don't really need *temporal acceleration* to break *synchronicity* and Linked Power. Those two make one of the most broken combinations in Psionics.

Comment: Synchronicity can't break the action economy, that trick has never actually worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, *temporal acceleration* gives you a round. The “next round,” from the perspective of a creature in *temporal acceleration*, is immediately after *temporal acceleration* ends, at which point the Linked Power occurs. *Synchronicity* goes off, you get whatever action you readied, and then you get your move and standard actions from the original turn in which you manifested *temporal acceleration* too.

However, I am stating for the record that I don’t suggest actually using *synchronicity*, particularly in conjunction with Linked Power, and especially not with Metapower. Getting three standard actions in one turn, as you suggest with your *temporal acceleration*, is pretty bad, though it does cost at least 13 PP. Adding extra standard actions to your next turn, as an immediate action (*grip of iron*, e.g., is 1st-level and manifests as an immediate), for just 1 PP (Metapower), tends to break the game into itty bitty pieces.

Comment: I am aware of all the gamebreaking uses of Synchronicity, Linked Power, Bestow Power and a psicrystal for recharging power points, and other combos for infinite actions. I agree, this is fun for no one. Specifically, what I am trying to achieve is a few more move actions so my character can move-Whirlwind-Attack-move, or a way to make Whirlwind Attack take a standard action without deep investment in a prestige class. If something comes to mind which does not break the game or get the DM to utter an infinite stream of "NO" while throwing dice at me, then I will gladly hear it.

Comment: @willardthor In *that* case, my [homebrew whirling dervish PrC](http://forum.faxcelestis.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=212) may be of interest to you. It's not really by best work, admittedly (the Existing Class Features thing was just ridiculous), but it's *perfect* for what you want to achieve, and as awkward as the wording is for Existing Class Features, the overall effect is balanced.

Answer (score 1):

i never figured out how that psicrystal linked power thing bestowed power points. I must be slow at this. But I did think about Temporal acceleration today and linked power, and concluded some third element would be necessary to make it worth doing, otherwise, you use the acceleration, giving you 1 round to activate A primary power, followed by the end of the acceleration, followed by the activation of the secondary power. But...linked power already does that, so you just wasted acceleration.

round 1: use linked power A
round 2: linked power B activates

vs.

Round 1: use acceleration
Round 1a: use linked power A while in a time freeze
Round 2: linked power B activates

Did I miss something here? it seems like you just spent more points for no reason. And if you did, you'd probably wish you had the synchronicity linked power bestow power loophole to get them back!

Comment: [Here's one way.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/75791/8610)