# Is there any character option to gain teleport (or any improved version) or the greater plane shift as an at will usage, other than racial ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, teleportation

Is there any character option to gain teleport (or any improved version) or greater plane shift, as an at will usage, other than racial ability?

I'm not really looking at items, except as a last resort. All official material suitable, but no extreme TO, please.

The goal is ideally to plane shift at will, accurately to the desired destination. Doing a two step plane shift and teleport is fine if the greater plane shift cannot be obtained.

Answer (score 5):

- Planar Shepherd, wildshape into any of the many outsider species that get Greater Teleport self-only at-will SLA. Unlike other methods of shape-shifting, Planar Shepherd can copy SLAs.
- Planeshifter (PrC from Manual of the Planes) gets regular Planeshift at-will.
- Get a Lantern Archon by any of several means: Planar Familiar (feat), Celestial Familiar (feat), Create Lantern Archon (Sanctified3 spell), Lesser Planar Ally (Clr4), or Lesser Planar Binding (Sor/Wiz5). It can't take passengers, but you can climb into a bag of holding and tell your familiar to teleport the bag.
- Justice Archon (MM4) gets regular Teleport at-will as a Su ability, not an SLA. Bebelith (MM1) gets regular Planeshift at-will as a Su ability. So that opens up options for copying Su abilities, such as Assume Supernatural Ability or Shapechange.
- Truenamer 20 gets at-will teleport to anyone who says your name. You'd still need to arrange for there to be such a creature at your destination.

Options I considered but which probably don't work:

- Spellthief X / Sha'ir 1 with both a Lantern Archon familiar (for greater teleport) and a Gen familiar (for planeshift)... But you'd need spellthief level 21 to steal a 7th-level SLA.
- Holy Transformation (Clr7) + persistomancy. This gives you the Archon subtype, which grants greater teleport self-only at-will, "unless otherwise noted in a creature's entry". Holy Transformation lists some benefits you get, and that list doesn't include teleport, but neither does it explicitly say you don't get the type traits not on the list. Clearly not intended, though.

Comment: I believe the Truenamer one requires your Truename.

Comment: @J.Mini No, because a 20th-level truenamer can choose a “true nickname” so to speak, so that someone does not need to make the Truenaming check to trigger that feature. Someone pointed out that you could choose “What” and create a truly hilarious rendition of the *Pulp Fiction* scene, since there is no limit on how often you can use that feature so you could pop in and out constantly as people question what is going on. (In case it wasn’t clear, nothing about the truenamer was well thought out.)

Comment: @KRyan I would going to object to this on the basis that it's still a Truename and therefore should be as hard to say as one, but the capstone clearly states that saying the nickname requires no True Speak check. You're right, they clearly didn't think this through. Pride only hurts, it never helps.

Answer (score 4):

## There are a few options, but none of them are pretty

As the 7th-level Clr and 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***greater plane shift*** [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 159) appears in only two sources—originally it's from the *Planar Handbook*—, it would be highly unusual to find in other sources game elements that generate an effect like it. The *3.5* editorial mandate was, generally, to assume that a consumer possessed only the core rules and the text involved, and there is no other mention in the *PlH* or the *SpC* of the spell *greater plane shift*. For example, no magic item has it as a prerequisite, no cleric domain includes it, no prestige class has it by name on its unique spell list, and no touchstone site grants it specifically as base ability or higher-order ability. As [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165720/8610) mentions, even a deity that uses to traverse the planes its divine characteristic [travel](http://dndsrd.net/divine.html#divine-characteristics-travel) (*Deities & Demigods* 30) ends up embarrassingly off-target! (Don't worry about that god, though—it deity can just teleport to the desired destination next round.)

This means you'll probably be stuck with the two-spell combination. Below I've listed some possibilities for achieving that combination at will.

- A level 9 [nomad](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPsion.html#psion) with a power point recharge trick (e.g. [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/75791/8610)) can employ a combination of the 5th-level nomad power [***psionic plane shift***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#plane-shift-psionic) [psychoportation] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 124) and the 5th-level psion/wilder [***psionic teleport***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersQtoW.html#teleport-psionic) [psychoportation] (136) to effectively accomplish what the question asks. From personal experience, such tricks aren't all theoretical: I have been both a DM of a campaign and a player in a different campaign wherein power point recharge tricks were allowed, and I didn't find the campaigns any more broken than the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* campaigns that forbade them. Still, while a few power point recharge tricks are *technically* legal, I suspect many DMs ban power point recharge tricks anyway, even though most require a significant investment of character resources.
- Like [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165723/8610) mentions, some creatures possess a usable-at-will supernatural ability that's like the spell [*plane shift*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#plane-shift) (e.g. a [bebilith](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#bebilith-demon) (*Monster Manual* 42)) or [*greater teleport*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#greater-teleport) (e.g. a creature that possesses the subtype [archon](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#archon) (16, 306)). A creature that can change its form into one or more of these creatures can take the feat **Assume Supernatural Ability** (*Savage Species* 30–1) and pick such an ability so as to use that ability at will while in the new form.

  For example, a level 12 sorcerer (who's type is probably outsider) that can cast the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) [tran] (*PH* 263) could take the feat twice—once for each ability—and satisfy the question's requirements, but that sorcerer likely must find a psion to use on her the 4th-level psion power [*psychic reformation*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#psychic-reformation) [telepathy] (*XPH* 127) if the desire is to do this at this low a level. Alternatively, the sorcerer could just wait until she can cast the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***shapechange***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shapechange) [trans] (*PH* 277–8) as that spell by default grants its subject an assumed form's supernatural abilities, no feats necessary.

  However, neither option in isolation *actually* accomplishes what the question asks. While the new form allows the creature to employ at will the effects the question wants, the method the creature uses to assume that form likely has use limits of its own (but see also, for example, the *phylactery of change* (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 135) (11,200 gp; 0 lbs.) and the [*skin of proteus*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsU.html#skin-of-proteus) (*XPH* 176) (84,000 gp; 2 lbs.)).
- A level 14 PC can spend the majority of her wealth on an [***amulet of the planes***](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#amulet-of-the-planes) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 247) (120,000 gp; 0 lbs.) that, in part, says that it

  > allows its wearer to utilize *plane shift*. However, this is a difficult item to master. **The user must make a DC 15 Intelligence check in order to get the *amulet* to take her to the plane (and the specific location on that plane) that she wants.** If she fails, the *amulet* transports her and all those traveling with her to a random location on that plane (01–60 on d%) or to a random plane (61–100).

  (Emphasis mine.) Ask the DM if the *amulet*'s description means that a successful Intelligence check transports the wearer with perfect accuracy. That is, the DM may rule that a successful check takes the wearer *both* to the desired plane *and* to "the specific location on that plane," the description making an exception to the normal operation of the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*plane shift*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#plane-shift) [conj] (*Player's Handbook* 262).  Alternatively, the DM may rule that the effect otherwise works identically to the spell *plane shift* therefore still depositing the wearer a woeful 5d% miles from the desired specific location on the picked plane despite a successful check. (To be clear, it's mainly the *amulet*'s price that supports the case for imprecise arrival.)

  (By the way, it could be unintentional, but the *amulet*'s description says that the *amulet* "allows its wearer to utilize *plane shift*" yet does *not* mandate the wearer use the effect *on herself!* Instead, the wearer can use a *plane shift* effect except that she must succeed on the Intelligence check to use the *amulet* to take *her* to the proper destination. It seems that the wearer can try to send another creature but not itself to other planes normally—that is, by touching that other creature—, and no Intelligence check's needed. Again, though, before investing 120,000 gp in an *amulet of the planes* for this purpose, run this by the DM.)
- As long as the creature can get to the destination a different way once, drop off an object safely, and confirm that the object will remain undisturbed at that destination, the creature can drop off at the destination one **moving *portal*** as per the feat **Create Moving Portal** (Perilous Gateways Web column "Portals of Anauroch: At'ar's Portal Collection"). Then the creature can use a *second* moving *portal* that leads to the first to travel at will to that first *portal*. Each moving portal has a market price of 125,000 gp, so a pair is only available to level 16 or higher PCs.

  (A keyed moving *portal* has the same price and can prevent unauthorized use, and it's likely the user will want the moving *portal* he's *not* carrying to be keyed! Also, this method assumes that it's dangerous or impractical to spend 3 months or so creating an actual fixed *portal* on another plane, but, y'know, if Diirinka is okay with the creator wintering in Hidden Betrayal or whatever, creating a normal nonmoving destination portal shaves 25,000 gp off the market price.)
- A level 21 character—usually a warlock—that meets its prerequisites can take the epic feat **Dark Transient** (Epic Insights Web column "Epic Warlock Feats") to gain the ability to

  > use *plane shift* with perfect accuracy (self and personal equipment only). [The warlock] can also transport other creatures, but [the warlock will] then suffer the inaccuracies normally incurred when using this spell [so work around this by having party members travel with the warlock in the warlock's *portable hole*]. Activating this ability requires a standard action.

  With such an ability, it's largely irrelevant for the question's purposes that the Dark Transient feat *also* grants an at-will effect similar to the *greater teleport* spell.
- As [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165723/8610) mentions, an epic **hellbreaker** (*Fiendish Codex I* 86–9) or an epic **spellthief** (*Complete Adventurer* 13–20) could "borrow" from a familiar or another ally a spell-like ability that's like the *greater teleport* or *plane shift* spell. This will likely be more difficult for a hellbreaker on her own, but a spellthief will probably have an improved familiar that could possess such a spell-like ability, albeit probably not both (see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140179/8610)).

By way of ancillary options, I would be remiss were I not to mention the ***[figurine of wondrous power](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#figurines-of-wondrous-power) ([obsidian steed](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#figurines-of-wondrous-power-obsidian-steed))*** (*DMG* 257) (28,500 gp; 0 lbs.) that can be activated for 24 hours 1 day per week and that's like a heavy warhorse "with the following additional powers usable once per round at will: *overland flight*, *plane shift*, and *ethereal jaunt*," the latter two also affecting the rider. I don't know in this context what a *power* is either, but a stable of seven *obsidian steeds*, while pricey, is certainly stylish, even if the rider must still provide her own *teleport* effect (or just reach the destination conventionally *via* flying horse).

Finally, a [**nightmare**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersMtoN.html#nightmare) (*MM* 194–5) can at will employ as a spell-like ability an effect like the spell [*astral projection*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#astral-projection) as a level 20 caster, and that spell voids the need for the combination altogether. A level 5 [blackguard](http://dndsrd.net/blackguard.html#blackguard) (*DMG* 181–3) (I know, right? And, so far as I'm aware, *only* a blackguard!) can replace her fiendish servant with a nightmare by taking the feat **Nightmare Steed** (*Polyhedron* #159 23).

---

***Note:*** With Wizards of the Coast's sudden but inevitable removal of its online 3.5 *repository, links to this answer's Web articles can't be provided easily. I hope enough information is given here so that an interested reader can hunt down those Web articles on another site.*

Comment: The Wayback Machine has pretty much all of the old 3.5e stuff, so you can search for something to find the dead link, and then put that in the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @KRyan I know, but It's that *searching to find the dead link* part that's a resource drain.

Answer (score 1):

Hellbreaker from *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells* is close to what you want, but doesn't give everything that you're after. Similarly, I'd suggest giving the Wayfarer Guide from *Completely Arcane* a look.

Sadly, I think that what you'll actually need is to [be a god](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm#travel) (see *Deities and Demigods*):

> A deity of rank 1 or higher can use greater teleport as a spell-like ability at will, as the spell cast by a 20th-level character, except that the deity can transport only itself and up to 100 pounds of objects per divine rank. A deity of rank 6 or higher also can use plane shift as a spell-like ability at will, as the spell cast by a 20th-level character, except that the deity can only transport itself and up to 100 pounds of objects.

Comment: Jaunter is probably as close as you can get to at-will.